# Getting Error While starting lite-server in npm

Tags: node.js, npm, lite-server

i did a fresh "npm init". put entry point : "index.html"

then installed lite-server : `npm install lite-server --save-dev`

also updated the package.json and I Uninstalled, reinstalled tried everything but it's not working and

also tried `npm cache clean --force` but it's not working. can any one help with this error.

```
    {
  "name": "git-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "npm run lite",
    "lite": "lite-server"
  },
  "author": "Sateesh",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.5.4"
  }
}
```

But when I did "npm start" , getting this error

```
 git-test@1.0.0 start D:\Coursera\git-test
> npm run lite
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! git-test@1.0.0 start: `npm run lite`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the git-test@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sai\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-05T10_20_11_723Z-debug.log
```

Comment: why not just `"start": "lite-server"`?

Comment: Sorry not worked @ManuelSpigolon

Comment: Hi, is `npm run lite` directly on the terminal also failing?

Comment: No same error @PraveenThirumurugan

Comment: Hi, can you quickly go to System Properties (Search Path) > Environment Variables > System Variables > Path > Edit > Find if NPM path is added.

Comment: Path settings checked. No Issue @PraveenThirumurugan

Answer (score 4):

I was too facing the same issue after a system shutdown, hence this worked for me:

First uninstall the current local lite-server in node_modules

```
npm uninstall lite-server
```

Install lite-server globally and try running the same command

```
npm install -g lite-server
```

then hit:

```
npm start
```

This fixed the issue for me, thank you

Here's my Json file script if you want to have a look

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run lite",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lite": "lite-server"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Just install the live-server globally,i think that should solve the issue.

```
sudo npm install --global lite-server
```

And in your package.json file you can change a little bit.

```
 {
  "name": "git-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "lite-server",
  },
  "author": "Sateesh",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
     "lite-server": "^2.5.4"
    }
  }
```

After this run this on terminal

```
npm start
```

I think this should help :)

Answer (score -1):

You don't seem to have node/npm installed and configured properly (PATH issues).

I would suggest you try to re-install Node.js using the official instructions for your platform (https://nodejs.org/en/download/) or by using a Node.js version manager like **nvm** (https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) or **n** (https://github.com/tj/n).

Using **nvm** or **n**, will allow you to dynamically switch Node.js version without having to re-install everything from scratch.

Comment: I think this is a wrong answer. Based on his logs, npm did work and invoked the start script.

Comment: this is the error, whih is clearly saying that npm is not available in the system PATH: "'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: Can just be a PATH issue alone.

Comment: Added @PraveenThirumurugan

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue,yarn start worked for

Comment: This is not an answer to the question